# MVC 3 How to create a controller's custrom access attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my application (MVC 3), I have a few types of users, and here's the typical - I guess - scenario: I want to restrict the access to some controllers for some of them, and also some of them can have access to the specified controller but not for all actions. I'm looking for some tips or articles how to create that scenario. Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: MVC has 2 attributes: `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]`. research them. they can be applied at controller or action level.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look into the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). You can also find more info [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/looking-at-how-asp-net-mvc-authorize-interacts-with-asp-net-forms-authorization.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

To restrict users from all the actions use AuthorizeAttribute over the whole controller.
But if you want to restrict the users to some selected actions use AuthorizeAttribute over the desired action (not over the whole Controller).
Again you can also restrict Authenticated users to some controller or action method by using Roles. Example:

```
[AuthorizeAttribute(Roles = "Employee")]
```